# Power BI Metadata extractor

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

Any PBIX file internally gets saved in different XML files like the DataMashup file, DataModeller etc. Is there any ready tool or script that is available to extract the metadata out of the PBIX file? Information that I am looking for is as below:

```
Measure Name | Formula | DataSource Name | Server Name | Database Name
```

Can we get this info from PowerBI Server or writing mcode ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [DAX Studio](https://daxstudio.org/). This will give you access to the DMVs behind your Power BI model.

In Particular you're interested in the [DMV MDSCHEMA_MEASURES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms126250(v%3Dsql.110)) which covers the majority of what you need. Some of your columns may be difficult though. In the case of Power BI one measure could potentially involve data from multiple data sources if you have a complicated model.